# Android OnDragListener for API 4?

Tags: android, listener

As you know, [`OnDragListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html) is started in **API level 11**

I want to use it but, unfortunately, I can't because my target devices are 1.6 and later (which are API 4).

Are there any alternative similar classes/libraries/ideas that might help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long long search, I didn't find something that works similar. So, I had to upgrade my target devices to use `OnDragListener` :(